# Disabling web security for Cypress tests preserves state - how to force cleanup?

Tags: security, cookies, cross-domain, cypress, same-origin-policy

For an E2E test using Cypress we have to set `chromeWebSecurity` to `false` in order to prevent CORS issue when running requests out of the Gitlab runner against the deployed backend. Unfortunately disabling this flag also causes unexpected side-effects such as local storage and cookies not being cleared between tests, preserving state hence tests not running in isolation and even causing non-deterministic behavior depending on their order.

A possible fix was to add a `beforeEach` with the following content in ALL `describe` blocks:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-ignore
// @ts-ignore
cy.clearCookies({ domain: null });
cy.clearLocalStorage();
```

Not only is this causing the tests to run longer, but having to manually add those multiple times across a single file is really cumbersome and prone to errors. Finally the first line is a hack as the `domain` option isn't documented and only internally available. I personally fear this option will be unavailable at some point and cause errors without a helpful error message and I really don't like to rely on internal implementation details.

Is there any other idiomatic and safe way to clean up the entire state while having `chromeWebSecurity` disabled?

Answer (score 0):

One sure way is to separate every case in different spec file. Between files npx cypress run closes the browser and starts it again